# How to iterate over 2+ lists at the same time

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm having three list with same length:

```
name = ['Snowball', 'Chewy', 'Bubbles', 'Gruff']
animal = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Fish', 'Goat']
age = [1, 2, 2, 6]
```

i want to iterate all three list in a single loop like:

```
for i,j,k in name,animal,age:
    print(i,j,k)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mukrramkhan/Documents/Mokaram Khan/projects/classes projects/python/oops.py", line 19, in <module>
    for i,j,k in name,animal,age:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Comment: You should look into `zip`, s default python keyword.